# jOOQ & PostgreSQL: mapping nested json object extracted from complex jsonb into custom type

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jooq

I use JSON objects in my PostgreSQL database. Stack is Java 11, Spring Boot 2+ with spring-boot-jooq-starter.

I often deserialize the a `jsonb` column into a complex type, using a `Binding` and a `Converter` that leverage Jackson for that. So far so good.

Now I do have a use case a bit more complex: I have a query that extracts a part of the json object (using the `jsonb_column::jsonb ->> nestedObject` operator in the select clause) into a field of my record.

I want to map that record into a pojo, so that all the fields of the record are mapped to field of the pojo (using the `@Column` annotation), and that particular json nested object should be mapped to a specific Java object.

What's the proper way to achieve that ?

Is there a way to do that using a binding and a `forcedType` (like I do to map the full `jsonb` column) ?

Shall I resort to a `RecordMapper` to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need two parts to implement this

#### 1. A data type binding for your nested object

This can be achieved using code like this:

```
DataType<NestedType> myType = SQLDataType.OTHER.asConvertedDataType(new YourBinding());
```

Where

```
class YourBinding implements Binding<Object, NestedType> { ... }
```

This binding will take care of mapping whatever the nested object structure looks like to your Java representation of that type. You will have to bind to JDBC directly to read the JSONB content.

Starting from jOOQ 3.12 ([see #7242](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7242)), there will be native `JSONB` support, using which you can implement your binding a bit more easily, i.e.

```
DataType<NestedType> myType = SQLDataType.JSONB.asConvertedDataType(new YourBinding());
class YourBinding implements Binding<JSONB, NestedType> { ... }
```

#### 2. A plain SQL template to express your nested object unnesting expression

You cannot provide the nested object extraction expression to the code generator easily for fetching data, so you will have to create a [plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) using the above data type

```
Field<NestedType> field = DSL.field("jsonb_column::jsonb ->> nestedObject", myType);
```

You can now use this `field` expression in all of your queries.